# Variable name is like function name -- when causes error/when doesn't

Tags: javascript

This question is about the *same names* of function and variable.
Please tell me -
why this code doesn't have errors:

```js
    var Task = new Task();
     
    function Task() {
        console.log('work!');
    }
```

but this one **won't work:**

```js
start();
 
function start() {
  var Task = new Task();
};
 
function Task() {
    console.log('work!');
}
```

Why it's so?

Comment: I think the downvotes are a _little_ harsh here - it's not immediately obvious why the redeclared `Task` variable works outside of the function but not inside.

Comment: Task isn't in the runtime when start is called. So it hasn't been defined yet. In the first example, Task is hoisted. In the second example, start is called first, so Task isn't in existence yet

Comment: @SterlingArcher Sure it is.  The issue is one of scope _and_ hoisting.  I don't have time to go into a full answer now though...

Comment: @JamesThorpe yup, but no worries. deceze answered it well enough lol

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: First: why would you do that? Second: as described in the [tour] ´questions about an actual problem´, so please explain your problem.

Comment: @inetphantom Not understanding why code works the way it works is not a real enough question and/or problem?

Comment: @deceze If it is ninjacode? There is no practicel use for that code. And to answer your question: Not as described by the [tour].

Comment: @inetphantom I just what use the same variable and class name. I think it's quite clear way for code style, isnt it? What do you use?

Comment: Your class is an object. The content of your variable is an object. It is not the same, so save it into two diffrent variables. Imo constructors are the only vars starting with a capital, so I would have `var Task` for the class (the constructor function) and `var task` for the instantiated object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through *name hoisting*, your first code essentially works like this:

```
var Task;  // (undefined)

Task = function () {
    console.log('work!');
};

Task = new Task();
```

Your second one like this:

```
var start, Task;

start = function () {
  var Task; // (undefined)
  Task = new Task();
};

Task = function () {
    console.log('work!');
};

start();
```

As you can see, `Task` is being overridden by `undefined` inside the `start` function. This does not happen when the function and variable definition are both in the same scope, since then `var` and `function` are essentially the same thing.

If you leave out the `var` inside `start`, it works as well.

Comment: I was typing up a similar answer, but I like this one much better.

Comment: This article may also be a good read: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting